# i want to show the processing data in progressbar text(variable) which is changing in doingBackground() method of an AsyncTask class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

[This image shows a fixed Text only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYxSL.png)

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // SaveAndCheck sac=new SaveAndCheck(getApplicationContext());
        System.out.println("comes");
        ar.clear();
        getContacts(check_string); 



        return null;
    }
```

get the contact name from getContacts(check_string) method; .want to show the name in progressbar

Comment: What is check_string???? Can you post your full AsyncTask please?

Comment: Can you post the full code please?

Comment: void getContacts( String check_string)
{
    char ch;
 for(int i=0;i<check_string.length;i++)
     ch=check_string.charAt(i); ///// i want to show the ch in  progress.showMessage(ch+"");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `runOnUiThread` inside your `doInBackGround()` method

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
              txtView.setText("VARIABLE");       
           }
        });
```

Or you just can use the [`onProgressUpdate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: void getContacts( String check_string)
{
    char ch;
 for(int i=0;i<check_string.length;i++)
     ch=check_string.charAt(i); ///// i want to show the ch in  progress.showMessage(ch+"");
}

Comment: @ovi009 Can update your code with your AsyncTask please?

Comment: ya got solution .thanks baby